# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_"

Tags: gfortran

I have a problem compiling codes with gfortran (gcc 8.3.0_2 installed using Homebrew) on MacOS Mojave. It came up with an error message as written in the title of this post. 
Would anyone please explain what went wrong and how to fix the problem. Thanks a ton!!

Adding flags -fno-PIC and -fno-PIE doesn't help.